# How to use existing resource on CNAME ARM Template

Tags: azure-rm-template

We are automating multi tenant application using ARM template and created all required resources. Finally we try to map CNAME with CDN. So that we try to add the CNAME in public DNS Zones. While we try add CNAME getting below error,

> 'The resource 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones/xxxxxx-domain.com' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.

We already tried below ARM template,

```
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnszones/CNAME",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('domainName'), '/',parameters('storage_account_name'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.cdn/profiles',parameters('storage_account_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "TTL": 3600,
        "targetResource": {
          "id": "[concat(resourceId('microsoft.cdn/profiles',parameters('storage_account_name')),'/endpoints/',parameters('storage_account_name'))]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "dnszones": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('DEV','Microsoft.Network/dnszones', parameters('domainName'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Already defined the 'Microsoft.Network/dnszones' in properties, but still getting the same error. Help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add Existing CDN Profile end points using below ARM template

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnszones/CNAME",
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('domainName'), '/',parameters('storage_account_name'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.cdn/profiles/endpoints',parameters('storage_account_name'),parameters('storage_account_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "TTL": 3600,
        "targetResource": {
          "id": "[concat(resourceId('microsoft.cdn/profiles/endpoints',parameters('storage_account_name'),parameters('storage_account_name')))]"
        }
      }
    }
```

And then add depends on [concat(parameters('domainName'), '/',parameters('storage_account_name'))] then remove target resource. Then it will work.